# How to clear heroku remote repository?

Tags: spring, git, heroku

My heroku slug size exceed the max limit of 300mb.. so i want to clear whole remote repo and redeploy everything. THe link i got is this:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo

as they suggest, to reset the repo,

```
heroku repo:reset -a appname
```

This will empty the remote repository. but I dont know, My repo size is still at 70mb.. and slug size is 389mb...same as before.. No change...Am i doing anything wrong?